# Click on last item in AdapterView in Espresso

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

I'm working on a note taking app. I add a note, and it get's added to the bottom of the list. As the last assertion in the espresso test, I want to make sure that the ListView displays a listItem that has just been added. This would mean grabbing the last item in the listView. I guess you might be able to do it in other ways? (e.g. get the size of adapted data, and go to THAT position? maybe?), but the last position of the list seems easy, but I haven't been able to do it. Any ideas?

I've tried this solution, but Espresso seems to hang. http://www.gilvegliach.it/?id=1

Answer (score 1):

**1. Find the number of elements in listView's adapter and save it in some variable. We assume the adapter has been fully loaded till now.**:

```
    final int[] numberOfAdapterItems = new int[1]; 
    onView(withId(R.id.some_list_view)).check(matches(new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) view;

            //here we assume the adapter has been fully loaded already  
            numberOfAdapterItems[0] = listView.getAdapter().getCount();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    }));
```

**2. Then, knowing the total number of elements in listView's adapter you can scroll to the last element**:

```
    onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.some_list_view)).getPosition(numberOfAdapterItems[0] - 1).perform(scrollTo())
```